# Enable azure diagonstic setting using ARM template for azure data factory,azure sql

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault

When I am enabling the diagonstic setting fromt the azure portal for ADF & Azuresql, in the ARM template I am not able to find anything in ARM with respect to diagonstic setting.Similar way for keyvault and sql I need the ARM template for enabling the diagonstic setting.

I tried from my side for ADF since I new to ARM template I am not able to find the method for enabling the diagonstic  setting.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "factoryName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the Data Factory"
            }
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories",
            "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
            "name": "[parameters('factoryName')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "identity": {
                "type": "SystemAssigned"
            },
            "properties": {
            },
            "resources": [
                {
                    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/providers/diagnosticSettings",
                    "apiVersion": "2017-05-01-preview",
                    "name": "[concat(parameters('factoryName'),'/microsoft.insights/', parameters('settingName'))]",
                    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[concat('Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/', parameters('factoryName'))]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "name": "[parameters('DS03')]",
                        "workspaceId": "[/subscriptions/3xxxxx-xxxxx-x-xxxx--xx/resourceGroups/BDAZxfdfG01]"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: pretty sure your workspaceId should not have `[]` in it and the type\name should not have parent in it, so type should start with `providers` and name should start with `microsoft.insights`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ARM template above is creating the diagnostic settings; however it is not actually configuring the logging of anything.  Add the following for all Data Factory metrics after your workspaceID property.

```
    "logAnalyticsDestinationType": "Dedicated",
    "logs": [
      {
        "category": "PipelineRuns",
        "enabled": true,
        "retentionPolicy": {
          "enabled": false,
          "days": 0
        }
      },
      {
        "category": "TriggerRuns",
        "enabled": true,
        "retentionPolicy": {
          "enabled": false,
          "days": 0
        }
      },
      {
        "category": "ActivityRuns",
        "enabled": true,
        "retentionPolicy": {
          "enabled": false,
          "days": 0
        }
      }
    ],
    "metrics": [
      {
        "category": "AllMetrics",
        "timeGrain": "PT1M",
        "enabled": true,
        "retentionPolicy": {
          "enabled": false,
          "days": 0
        }

      }
    ]
```

Besides configuring the diagnostic settings what metrics and diagnostics must be select to send to log analytics.  These fields align to those on the diagnostic blade:
[image]

The "logAnalyticsDestinationType": "Dedicated" is to ensure the logs go to their own table as opposed to the default AzureDiagnostic table.  There is [documented limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/resource-logs-collect-workspace) in the original table.

Comment: Hi Dreadedfrost, I got this point logAnalyticsDestinationType": "Dedicated"  and working fine for ADF, Now I am looking for Azure sql & Azure keyvault ARM template if you have anything to share please let me know.

Comment: @anuj please accept the above answer if it is working.  Not all resources support [dedicated destination tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/diagnostic-logs-schema) Just remove this from your ARM template as the default will go to the AzureDiagnostic table. For your other resources you can either pull them up in the portal and see what diagnostic settings there are. For example Key Vault has log-> AuditEvent and metric-AllMetrics